# Automatically redirects to another page without doing any action.I'm using php and jquery in the page

Tags: php, jquery, redirect

I have a php page which uses jquery also for loading another page in sidebar. When I click on any sidebar link, it will redirect to one page which shows the detail of the clicked link. Everything is working perfectly in my system. I checked in other two more systems. It's working perfectly. But I installed it in server, first few days, it was working fine. But now, whenever I load that page, it automatically redirects to the page which I loaded to the sidebar.

Eg: Main page: `Billing_home.php`
    Sidebar Page: `Call_lead.php`
    Redirect to : `Lead_details.php` ( Only when I click on a lead in sidebar)
When `Billing_home.php` loads, it Automatically redirecting to `Call_lead.php`

But Everything is working fine in my system. When they access it from server, it happens like that. What should I do? Please help

Comment: no one can help you without seen the code

Comment: Please add the code so we can check it, as says @SupunFictionPraneeth